# Defining a special edge style for connecting nodes in forest

Tags: linguistics, forest

I want to draw certain edges in a dependency tree with a piece of line pointing upwards as in the following picture:

[image]

The code for this is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}


\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V,l sep=2\baselineskip
  [N
    [D [the] ]
     [child] ]
  [Adv,name=often [often]]
  [reads]
  [N
    [D [the] ]
    [book] ]
  [Adv,name=slowly [slowly]] ]
\draw (often.north)--($(often.north)+(0,.3)$);
\draw (slowly.north)--($(slowly.north)+(0,.3)$);
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

The `forest` manual has different styles for edges (p. 33). I would like to define a style for such edges, so that I could write `[Adv, edge=adjunct]`. The perfect solution should also take the space that is necessary to draw the upward line into account, so that I could drop the `l sep`specification above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option `edge path` also documented at page 33.
It contains the code that generates the edge.
By default it is

```
edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor)--(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
```

we can modify it (on a per-node basis) to produce an extra bit on top of the child:

```
edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor)--(.child anchor)-- +(0,10pt)\forestoption{edge label};}
```

the `10pt` is arbitrary here.

One can then bundle it into a style `adjunct` and use it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}


\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}}},
adjunct/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
(!u.parent anchor)--(.child anchor)-- +(0,#1)\forestoption{edge label};}},
adjunct/.default=10pt
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V,l sep=2\baselineskip
  [N
    [D [the] ]
     [child] ]
  [Adv,adjunct [often]]
  [reads]
  [N
    [D [the] ]
    [book] ]
  [Adv,adjunct=20pt [slowly]] ] % 20pt just for demonstration
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

---

From the manual:

> The node positioning algorithm is sensitive to edges, i.e. it will
>   avoid a node overlapping an edge or two edges overlapping. However,
>   the positioning algorithm always behaves as if the `edge path` had the
>   default value — *changing the `edge path` does not influence the packing!*
>   Sorry.

so it would seem there is no easy way to make `forest` aware of the extra bit in these edges, so the spacing must be adjusted manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This manual is very complex and I would never have made it. The parameter and the default is very cool!

Comment: About edge sensitivity: the `edge boundary path` option has just moved up on my todo list! ;-)